# Android Wear detect ambient screen mode

Tags: android, wear-os, watch, ambient

Is there a way to detect when the watch is in ambient screen mode? I make a watch face and want to continue to update the clock when the ambient screen mode is on (clock is shown on screen), but I want to stop updating when the screen is off. For now, I start and stop the update in `onPause` and `onResume` methods, but the `onPause` method is called when the ambient screen mode comes on.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be notified of the Ambient mode changed, you have to use a `DisplayListener`.
You can find the way to do that [here](https://gist.github.com/PomepuyN/cdd821eca163a3279de2)

Comment: Android Wear has this built into the WearableActivity with onEnterAmbient and onExitAmbient as outlined below.

Comment: Oops, spoke too soon, they just added a better approach (AmbientMode.AmbientCallbackProvider). I outlined details below.

Answer (score 1):

The normal way is to use android WearableActivity and implement `onEnterAmbient` and `onExitAmbient`.

And of cause, there's another way, use `DisplayListener` to check whether display state is `DOZE` or `DOZE_SUSPEND`.

Answer (score 0):

You should implement the `AmbientMode.AmbientCallbackProvider`
callback instead.

It is the new preferred method and it still gives you the `onEnterAmbient()`, `onAmbientUpdate()`, and `onExitAmbient()` but also lets you use `Activity` (or any sub classes... FragementActivity, etc.). It also allows you to support the Architecture components.

[Official docs call out the details (and example code)](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/always-on.html):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements AmbientMode.AmbientCallbackProvider {

    /*
     * Declare an ambient mode controller, which will be used by
     * the activity to determine if the current mode is ambient.
     */
    private AmbientMode.AmbientController mAmbientController;
    …
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ...
        mAmbientController = AmbientMode.attachAmbientSupport(this);
    }
    ...

    …
    @Override
    public AmbientMode.AmbientCallback getAmbientCallback() {
        return new MyAmbientCallback();
    }
    …

private class MyAmbientCallback extends AmbientMode.AmbientCallback {
    @Override
    public void onEnterAmbient(Bundle ambientDetails) {
             // Handle entering ambient mode
    }

    @Override
    public void onExitAmbient() {
      // Handle exiting ambient mode
     }

    @Override
    public void onUpdateAmbient() {
      // Update the content
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not work unless DISPLAY->ALWAYS ON=ENABLED, is there a way around this?