# WatchFace colors based on date/time

Tags: java, android, wear-os

I am trying to create a WatchFace that has an AM/PM paint, and I want to be different colors based on if it is AM or PM. I also want to extend this to the days of the week.

SimpleWatchFace.java

```
Paint ampmPaint = new Paint();
final SimpleDateFormat amorpm = new SimpleDateFormat("a", Locale.US);
if (amorpm.format(new Date()).equals("AM")) {
    ampmPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
}
else {
    ampmPaint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
}
ampmPaint.setTextSize(context.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.ampm_size));
ampmPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
ampmPaint.setTextSize(context.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.ampm_size));
ampmPaint.setAntiAlias(true);

...

public void setAmColor(int color) {
    ampmPaint.setColor(color);
}

public void setPmColor(int color) {
    ampmPaint.setColor(color);
}
```

SimpleWatchFaceService.java

```
@Override
public void onAmbientModeChanged(boolean inAmbientMode) {
    super.onAmbientModeChanged(inAmbientMode);
    watchFace.setAntiAlias(!inAmbientMode);

        if(inAmbientMode) {
            watchFace.setPmColor(Color.GRAY);
            watchFace.setAmColor(Color.GRAY);
        }
        else {
            watchFace.setPmColor(Color.GREEN);
            watchFace.setAmColor(Color.RED);
        }
        invalidate();
    }
```

So far, the color works on interactive mode, but as soon as it goes to ambient mode and back to interactive mode, the colors don't work, and I know my code does not work. I am wondering how I would fix my code so it goes back to color in interactive mode

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`u`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to get the day of the week (1 = Monday, 7 = Sunday). Also note that

```
if (amorpm.equals("AM")){
```

will always return `false`, because you are checking if the `SimpleDateFormat` is equal to a `String`. Correct usage would be:

```
SimpleDateFormat amorpm = new SimpleDateFormat("a", Locale.US);
SimpleDateFormat dayofweek = new SimpleDateFormat("u", Locale.US);
if (amorpm.format(new Date()).equals("AM")) {
    // AM
    ...
```

and (note that you can [`switch`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/strings-switch.html) on Strings now):

```
switch (dayofweek.format(new Date()) {
    case "1":
        // Monday
        ...
```

As for the ambient mode, to detect that you'll need a [`DisplayListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/display/DisplayManager.DisplayListener.html) as per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27184148/android-wear-detect-ambient-screen-mode).

Comment: For the ambient mode, I am using onAmbientModeChanged, and have this inside a if/else statement, watchFace.setAmPmColor(Color.GRAY);. public void setAmPmColor(int color) {
        ampmPaint.setColor(color);
    }

Comment: I edited my question to better phrase what I am trying to do